# imagejpeg - Unable to open file for writing: Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions

I am getting this error / warning:

> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open
>   '/var/www/my_web/data/my_web/www/users/avatars/user125.jpg' for
>   writing: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/my_web/data/classes/class.Image.php on line 157

On line 157, there is

```
  imageJPEG($image, $this->destPath, $this->jpgQuality);
```

My avatars folder has permission set to 777, `$this->destPath` is `'/var/www/my_web/data/my_web/www/users/avatars/user125.jpg'`

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set destination path to 777 permission with user `www-data`

be careful with the user-group : `www-data`

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/my_web/data/my_web/www/users/avatars/
```

"The "-R" stands for "recursive" which means that the command will affect every single file within the directory you choose." (from comments @lefdilia)

Comment: What does `chmod -R` do?

Comment: "The "-R" stands for "recursive" which means that the command will affect every single file within the directory you choose."

Answer (score 5):

You should set 777 permission for jpeg file too.
Check permission of jpg.